# Cannot reset a loop in a plugin template

Tags: plugins, loop, reset

I am trying to override a query in a loop which exists in other plugin. I created an extension to override that loop using a hook that exists in the plugin.

The plugin query:

```
query_posts ($args);
/*
Some codes
*/
do_action('the_action_Triggered');
/*
the loop
*/
```

In my extension:

```
add_action('the_action_Triggered','geo_srt_reset_query',200,1);
function geo_srt_reset_query(){
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set('meta_key','place_order');
    $wp_query->set('orderby','meta_value_num title');
    $wp_query->set('order','ASC');

    //print_r($wp_query);
    query_posts($wp_query->query_vars); // i tried with this line and without it.
}
```

The problem is that the query results or affected doesn't change. So if you think you can offer some help, please don't hesitate.

Comment: It is of absolute no use declaring the `$wp_query` global in your code when you just stuff everything up later on with the use of `query_posts`. IMHO, the plugin you are using are a heap of crap, sorry to say and you would be better of without it. Golden rule, never ever use `query_posts`. I would rewrite the complete plugin to bring it up to standard :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete and you have omitted all the context for some weird reason.

I hope we agree that `query_posts()` is a bad idea. There's enough been said on it:

[When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

Having said that, have you tried `wp_reset_postdata`, `wp_reset_query` or `rewind_posts`? I have no idea what you are doing here, but you can read this and figure which one to use:

http://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/